# Is there a way I can resize my lines of code in HTML shorter so links don't overlap?

Tags: html

[Atom snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNEq7.png) 
Is there a way I can resize my lines of code in HTML shorter so links don't overlap? I am new and would like to learn more on this tool.

Comment: So links do not overlap? Like add line breaks?

Comment: Are you looking for settings in your specific editor? or general formatting suggestions to reduce line length?

Comment: Use a plugin like https://atom.io/packages/atom-prettify ??

Comment: Thank you, I am fairly new to atom and the whole coding world. Just installed the pack, now how do I run it to format my script and make it look nicer, more in line and organized?

Comment: Please copy/paste the code as text instead of as image